# Usage of "by" in SO advertisement

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Today I saw the following ad while browsing [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com):

[image]

It says:

> **Make your next move**
>
> with a career site
>
> that's by developers

Now, I can think of three ways to read this:

1. "Make your next move [...] by developers" as in "by the help of developers".
2. "[...] a career site that's by developers" as in "by developers' side".
3. "[...] a career site that's by developers" as in "By developers, for developers".

Still, those readings don't really match the given sentence. In the last case I could accept a standalone "By developers" or "By developers, for developers". But I haven't seen "by" used within a sentence in such a way "that's by someone". Shouldn't there be a verb preceding "by developers", e.g. "built by developers"? if not, how is "by" used in this context?

Comment: True... this can be improved for sure! :)

Comment: @Maulik Does it seem unusual to a native speaker - or is it acceptable 'advertisement language'?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I've written many ads; in fact, ads need clearer language. Let others come and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, I'd say that the English on it's own means "made by developers".

However, it's an ad within a context, and the target audience would naturally intuit that to mean that it specializes in handling the IT job market.  So it takes more than English to completely glean the meaning, which you rightfully stated as "by developers **and for developers**".